# View helper for mongoid-pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, kaminari, mongoid3

In rails, does mongoid-pagination have a view helper that will automatically render the pagination links on a view on which it is applied? Do I have to build my own one instead.

For example with Kaminari you can use <%= paginate @pets %> on your view and you get the pagination links ( **Prev 1 2 3 Next** ).

Answer (score 0):

Kaminari can actually [support](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#orm--template-engine-agnostic) Mongoid. Maybe you can explore that area.

Comment: Yes I already have Kaminari in place. I was trying to avoid adding a gem which brings capabilities that are already provided by the Mongoid driver.